# I need a hint in solving Cauchy problem for differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, cauchy-problem

I need a hint for the following problem. It seems that separating variables does not work. Please leave just a hint not a whole solution.

Solve the Cauchy problem.
$y'(x)=\frac{x^{2}}{2+\sin(x^{2})}\cos((y(x))^{2})\;\; and\;\; y(0)=0 .$

(a) Prove that there exist one and only one solution defined for every $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

(b) Prove that 
$y(x)\to \sqrt{\pi/2}$
as
$x\to +\infty.$

Comment: Try first showing that $[-\sqrt{\pi/2}, \sqrt{\pi/2}]$ is a trapping region for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: This will allow you to use the fact that $$f : [-x_{\mathrm{max}}, x_{\mathrm{max}}]\times [-\sqrt{\pi/2}, \sqrt{\pi/2}]\to \mathbb{R}^+, (x, y)\mapsto \frac{x^2}{2+\sin(x^2)}\cos(y^2)$$ is continuous in $x$ and uniformly Lipschitz in $y$ for any given $x_{\mathrm{max}} > 0$. Try using Picard existence at that point.